# What are paddingStart and paddingEnd?

Tags: android, android-layout

Since few times the autocomplete box from Eclipse propose android:paddingStart android:paddingStop when I'm writing xml layout files.

I don't really understand what those attributes are supposed to do.

The eclipse/javadoc documentation is not really helpful :
`Sets the padding, in pixels, of the start edge; see padding.` and the online documentation does not make any reference to those attributes : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Could you explain me ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After reading into the Android source code (View.java) it seems paddingStart and paddingEnd are helpful to take care of letter direction (left to right of right to left) defined by the user.

Thus, paddingStart is interpreted as paddingLeft in LTR (left-to-right) languages and paddingRight in RTL (right-to-left) languages.

Source code from View.java (android-4.0.1) :

```
    switch (getResolvedLayoutDirection()) {
        case LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL:
            // Start user padding override Right user padding. Otherwise, if Right user
            // padding is not defined, use the default Right padding. If Right user padding
            // is defined, just use it.
            if (mUserPaddingStart >= 0) {
                mUserPaddingRight = mUserPaddingStart;
            } else if (mUserPaddingRight < 0) {
                mUserPaddingRight = mPaddingRight;
            }
            if (mUserPaddingEnd >= 0) {
                mUserPaddingLeft = mUserPaddingEnd;
            } else if (mUserPaddingLeft < 0) {
                mUserPaddingLeft = mPaddingLeft;
            }
            break;
        case LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR:
        default:
            // Start user padding override Left user padding. Otherwise, if Left user
            // padding is not defined, use the default left padding. If Left user padding
            // is defined, just use it.
            if (mUserPaddingStart >= 0) {
                mUserPaddingLeft = mUserPaddingStart;
            } else if (mUserPaddingLeft < 0) {
                mUserPaddingLeft = mPaddingLeft;
            }
            if (mUserPaddingEnd >= 0) {
                mUserPaddingRight = mUserPaddingEnd;
            } else if (mUserPaddingRight < 0) {
                mUserPaddingRight = mPaddingRight;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Also note that they don't seem to be public. At least Eclipse won't compile them for me.

Comment: @Timmmm gotta have target set to api 17+ for it to compile.

Comment: @schwiz api 17 was not available at this time. But now, you can to set api level at 17 in order to use those fields.

Answer (score 1):

**Padding** is used to add a blank space between a view and its contents.

- `android:paddingStart` Sets the padding at the start edge means at
  the left side of view
- `android:paddingEnd` Sets the padding at the end edge means at the
  right side of view
- `android:paddingBottom` Sets the padding at the bottom edge
- `android:paddingTop` Sets the padding at the top edge

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When working with and reading this I realize it is paddingStart and paddingEND and not paddingSTOP (although this element exists).