# android:paddingLeft gives an error?

Tags: android, xml

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Consider replacing android:paddingLeft with android:paddingStart="5dp" to better support 
 right-to-left layouts
- When you define paddingLeft you should probably also define paddingRight for right-to-left 
 symmetry
```

in my xml file i got this type of error why this happen any one have idea why this happen.

here is my xml file

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/titles"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"  // here am getting that error
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/productTitle"
                    style="@style/darkGreyMediumText14"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:text="Samsung  " />
                />
```

Answer (score 6):

add the attribute `tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"` to remove this warning/error. This should not be an error IMO though.

Comment: Can u Please Give some Example, Why it Happens?

Comment: This does not remove warnings in eclipse's layout editor.

Comment: Any way to ignore it once for the whole project?

Answer (score 4):

I follow the instruction of Mr.Vinay Wadhwa to fix the issues,But the time of implementation i got little bit confused where i have to use this,So thats why have to put this code for the clear reference.

**Include this property in Parent Layout**

1. xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
2. tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" >
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can add both `android:paddingLeft="10dp"` and `android:paddingStart="10dp"` with same value.So when android render RTL layout it will consider paddingStart else paddingLeft..

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL

Answer (score 0):

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>   - Consider replacing android:paddingLeft with android:paddingStart="5dp" to better support right-to-left  layouts
>   - When you define paddingLeft you should probably also define paddingRight for right-to- symmetry

These seem like warnings rather than errors. Warnings dont prevent your code from compiling. Rather, they show you some extra care that you need to take.

Why are you getting these?
Well, the annotations themselves have given you the answer. `paddingStart` is interpreted as `paddingLeft` in LTR languages and `paddingRight` in RTL languages. Hard-coding the direction will lead to strange layout in different languages.

If you are sure that you are only going to support LTR languages like English and the likes, go ahead and keep it as `paddingLeft`

Source: [What are paddingStart and paddingEnd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160105/what-are-paddingstart-and-paddingstop)

Comment: except it gives an ERROR, which doesn't let us run the app.